# Flash upload to server

Tags: flash, upload

my baner is considered unsafe because of 
`fileHandler.upload function` 
which uploads selected image to server. Is there any other function I can use to replace fileHandler.upload ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try a [POST request](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/loadVars/page02.php)